# Expresión regular que detecte al menos un carácter repetido

Tags: java, regex

Estoy intentado hacer una expresión regular que detecte si una cadena tiene mínimo 5 caracteres y al menos uno de ellos se repite, estoy intentando algo así:

"([\d]?[\d]){5,}"

Pero creo que estoy utilizando mal esta expresión:

(?[\d])

Las cadenas aceptadas serían:

123451

12321

111111

Las rechazadas serían:

1232

123456

123456789

Comment: Los caracteres válidos son únicamente dígitos? Lo infiero porque los casos que coloca en la pregunta son solo de dígitos. Si es así por favor edite la pregunta indicando ademas que deben ser solo digitos. Otra cosa que debe ackarar es si la expresion regular debe hacer match solo con cadenas completas o no. Por ejemplo: es válido que la expresion regular haga match con la cadena "12341 123" siendo que una parte de ella cumple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución propuesta utiliza dos características de las expresiones regulares `backreference` y `non-consuming`

- `backreference` permite utilizar una captura en la evaluación de la expresión. Para este caso particular la porción del patrón que hace uso de esta característica es  `(.)(.)*\\1` que define `(.)` cualquier caracter `(.)` seguido de cero o mas caracteres cualquiera `(.)*` y que se repita la captura del primer grupo `\1` el cual es el primer caracter que se capturó
- `non-consuming` permite definir que un grupo no consuma la línea de evaluación; es decir que la evaluación del siguiente patrón de la expresión regular se continua evaluando donde empezó la captura del patrón que se declaró como `non-consuming` el grupo que se declara como `non-consuming` se define encerrándolo entre `(?=` y `)` . Para el caso particular de lq pregunta se define en primer lugar el cumplimiento de por lo menos 5 dígitos `(?=[\d]{5,})` modo `non-consuming`

El patron de expresión regular resultante propuesto para la pregunta es `(?=[\d]{5,})(?=(.)(.)*\1)` que indica que la captura debe tener en primer lugar 5 o mas dígitos y que en la misma captura debe repetirse cualquier caracter por lo menos una vez

A continuación un programa en `java` que utiliza el patrón de expresión regular propuesto evaluado contra las cadenas de entrada que se expone en la pregunta por el método `lookingAt()` de la clase `Pattern`.
Se asume que los caracteres que se requieren son dígitos, considerando que los casos presentados en la pregunta se limitan a dígitos; pero en cualquier caso se puede cambiar el grupo de caracteres fácilmente si se desea ampliarlo.

```
import java.util.regex.*;  

class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Declaracion de casos
        String[] casos;
        casos = new String[] {
            "123451",
            "12321",
            "111111",
            "1232",
            "123456",
            "123456789"
        };
       
       //Definicion del patron de la expresion regular
       String sPat;
       sPat = "(?=[\\d]{5,})(?=(.)(.)*\\1)";
       Pattern p;
       p = Pattern.compile(sPat);

        //Evaluacion de la expresion regular para cada uno de los casos
        for(String cad : casos)
        {
            Matcher m;
            m = p.matcher(cad);  
            boolean bres;
            //Calcula el valor de la funcion
            
            bres = m.lookingAt();
            System.out.println(cad + ": lookingAt(..)=" + bres);
            
        }
    }
}
```